# Tesseract / PYOCR detects 'Z' as '2'

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am using pyocr (https://github.com/openpaperwork/pyocr) for my application, its all working good with the exception of the following:

From this image:

[image]

Tesseract will extract:

**42Z8**

It detects one of the Zs but not the other 'Z', this is important because this number passes throught a validation that fails if this problem happens.

**Things i tried:**

1. Using font (flama) .traineddata file with tesseract, didnt fix.
2. Isolate the block like the image to see the detection was better.
3. Doing some image processing like:

> thresh = cv.threshold(blocktext, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

How can i fix this ? Maybe the solution is some more complex image processing but i am bit lost at the moment.

Thank you.

**Updated image:**

[image]

Comment: If the format is same all the time (one digit, two letters, one digit) then you can limit the characters tesseract is looking for. Look only for digits and look only for characters. Then combine the results.

Answer (score 6):

I used `pytesseract, tesseract 4.0 and tessdata_best`.

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('4zz8.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
adaptiveThresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 12)

config = '-l eng --oem 1 --psm 3'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(adaptiveThresh, config=config)

print("Result: " + text)

cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.imshow('adaptiveThresh', adaptiveThresh)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: result]

Output is:

```
Result: 4 ZZ8
```

Comment: I am sorry, the image i added is not the processed image in wich i want to ocr the text, i updated the image from the one where i want the text. Thank you.

Comment: Try follow @Ozcan suggestion. The characters are too similar, so you must find another way to preprocess them (or fine tune the one above).

Comment: I will try, but it will be random until something works, do you have any guess of what could work ?

Comment: Hi @Link can o plase tell me how to use `tessdata_best`? Do I have to download it and then paste it where? There is not a single tutorial about it..I am using Linux and Conda

Comment: A simple search led me to this:


An installer for the OLD version 3.02 is available for Windows from our download page. This includes the English training data. If you want to use another language, download the appropriate training data, unpack it using 7-zip, and copy the .traineddata file into the 'tessdata' directory, probably C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata.


https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#windows

Comment: I solved using config = '-l eng --oem 1 --psm 3' good recognition between z and 2, now my problem is l to 1

Comment: That worked for me. Changing the tessdata from fast to best solved all my problems and I also helped remove unnecessary filters